# C# Why does System.Text.Json doesnt deserialise string

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

Given this model class:

```
    using System.Text.Json;
    public class QueueMessage
    {
        public int MerchantId { get; }
        public string Message { get; }
    }
```

When I try to deserialize a json string into the type QueueMessage, the fields are set to default. 0 and null.
This is how I've tried to deserialize it:

```
var jsonString = "{\"MerchantId\":2,\"Message\":\"Message 2\"}";
QueueMessage message  = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<QueueMessage>(jsonString, new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        });

message.Message is null
message.MerchantId is 0
```

I'm using .Net 5 by the way.

**What have I tried**
Well i try to use my ol' buddy Newtonsoft.Json

```
dynamic message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
dynamic mercId = message.MerchantId.Value; //THIS gives the expected value of 2
```

However,

```
QueueMessage msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueueMessage>(jsonString);
```

Gives the 0, null result

Now, the question is why does deserializing to a typed object fail?

Comment: Can you put a try catch block and check the exception?

Comment: Seems like your model has only getters. Without setters, the deserializer can not assign values to the properties

Comment: @GoodboY STJ supports `[JsonConstructor]` now (finally), so you _can_ use constructed-types as DTOs again, which is good, because mutable DTOs make me feel uncomfortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add setters to your properties, otherwise the deserializer can't assign values to those properties

```
public class QueueMessage
{
    public int MerchantId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `string Message` should be marked as nullable (i.e. ``public string? Message { get; set; }`) because when you use mutable setters without a ctor there's no guarantee that the property will actually be non-`null` after deserialiation.

Answer (score 2):

- As an alternative to Ziv's answer, and if you value the benefits of constructed types and/or immutability, recent versions of `System.Text.Json` [now support `\[JsonConstructor\]`, so you can now  use constructed DTO types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-immutability?pivots=dotnet-6-0).
- In my opinion you should *always* also specify an explicit `[JsonPropertyName]` to protect against DTO/JSON breakages caused by renamed properties or changing project-wide `camelCase` vs `PascalCase` JSON serialization settings.

  - It's also my opinion that JSON object members should always use `camelCase`, not `PascalCase` as that's the capitalization convention used by JavaScript/TypeScript, which is the usual target for JSON types ([unfortunately STJ defaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties) to `PascalCase` (*grrrr*))

---

#### Example 1: With a simple constructor

- ...though this isn't a good example as it doesn't show the ctor actually doing anything useful.

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

public class QueueMessage
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public QueueMessage(
        int     merchantId,
        string? message
    )
    {
        this.MerchantId = merchantId;
        this.Message    = message;
    }

    [JsonPropertyName("merchantId")] public int     MerchantId { get; }
    [JsonPropertyName("message")   ] public string? Message    { get; }
}
```

#### Example 2: With validating constructor

- Because the constructor can make assertions and validate parameters it means the ctor can prevent `QueueMessage.Message` from ever being `null`, so the `String?` property can be changed to `String` which makes consuming the DTO nicer - and it can also validate `MerchantId` too:

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

public class QueueMessage
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public QueueMessage(
        int    merchantId,
        string message
    )
    {
        this.MerchantId = merchantId > 0 ? merchantId : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( paramName: nameof(merchantId), actualValue: merchantId, message: "Value must be positive and non-zero." );
        this.Message    = message ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(message));
    }

    /// <summary>Always &gt;= 1.</summary>
    [JsonPropertyName("merchantId")] public int    MerchantId { get; }

    /// <summary>Never null.</summary>
    [JsonPropertyName("message")   ] public string Message    { get; }
}
```

#### Example 3: With `record class`

- To keep things simpler, you could also just use a `record class`.

  - Though this loses the validation logic, so `Message` is now `String?` again.
- Use the syntax `[property: ]` to apply `JsonPropertyName` and other attributes to `record class` properties via their ctor parameter names.

```
public record class QueueMessage(
    [property: JsonPropertyName("merchantId")] int     MerchantId,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("message")   ] string? Message
);
```